# Positioning in Load all Subfile

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have a Load all subfile with features that allow users to take options on records that will update the records.

What I want to be able to do is as soon as a record is updated by the user, the subfile should be redisplayed to show the updated data.

I can call the Build_Subfile routine that will redisplay the subfile. However what would happen is, the subfile is displayed from the first record. However, I want the same positioning to be maintained. I understand that this can be done if the RRN of first row currently displayed when the option is taken is saved and restored during the redisplay. But as this is a load all subfile, is it possible to retrieve the RRN?

Answer (score 2):

The keyword you're looking for is SFLRCDNBR. This tells the program to display the page of the subfile with the given RRN on it.

In the display file, in the subfile control record, you'll need to add this keyword:

```
     A            CSRRRN         4S 0H      SFLRCDNBR(CURSOR)
```

This tells the subfile to display the subfile page containing the RRN that you set in CSRRRN. So, for example, if you had 10 records on a page and you set CSRRRN to 15, the subfile would start on the 2nd page where 15 is located. Note that when using this method, CSRRRN must **always** be a non-zero number when the subfile is displayed, or the program will fault with a display file error.

Now in your RPG, when the user is selecting records for update, capture the RRN during the ReadC or Chain routine that's checking for selected records. You didn't post your code, so this is pseudo-code, but you get the idea.

```
/Free
 // Read through the subfile
 ReadC SubfileA;
 Dow Not %EOF;
   If Select = '1'; // User chose this record
     Exsr srUpdate; // Update the record
     CSRRRN = RRN#A; // Also set cursor to this RRN so the subfile returns here
   Endif;
   ReadC SubfileA;
 Enddo;
/End-Free
```

In your Build_Subfile routine, you'll want to trap for CSRRRN = 0 and change it to prevent the display file error I mentioned above. This would only happen on an initial subfile load, or if you wanted to reposition the subfile to the top for whatever reason.

```
/Free
 Begsr Build_Subfile;
   If CSRRRN = *Zero;
     CSRRRN = 1; // Position to the top
   Endif;

   // Load your records here
 Endsr;
/End-Free
```